# Select last column record with group_by

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table like this:

```
----------------------------------
| post | page_likes | created_at |
----------------------------------
|   2  |     700    | 2017-11-02 |
----------------------------------
|   1  |     702    | 2017-11-03 |
----------------------------------
|   4  |     709    | 2017-11-04 |
----------------------------------
|   2  |     712    | 2017-11-05 |
----------------------------------
|   0  |     710    | 2017-11-06 |
```

And a query to calculate data and use it for my chart

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%m') as ymd_id,
                  page_likes AS page_likes,
                  sum(post) AS total_posts

                  FROM table
                    Where created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-02 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-6 00:00:00'
                  GROUP BY ymd_id
                  ORDER BY ymd_id ASC
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------
|total_posts| page_likes |   ymd_id   |
---------------------------------------
|     9     |     700    |   201711   |
---------------------------------------
```

page_like goes wrong. It takes 700, but the value i want is 710.

Is there a way to modify the query above to get last row of page_like?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Please _edit_ your question and clearly show us the sample input and the output you expect.  Your current query is rife with problems and I can't even attempt an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen edited

Comment: No, this doesn't help.  The "result" doesn't have a column called `total_posts`, which clearly appears in the query.

Comment: Okami X Oukarin, I think you miss the point about aggregation function works with Group By here. Only the aggregation result, here is `sum(post) as total_posts`, and the group by column, here your `DATE_FORMAT as ymd_id`, are guaranteed. Any other column added to the result set will be incorrect, as they are not part of either the GROUP_BY clause or the aggregation function.

Comment: I'm more than happy to answer your question, but I need to understand what that question is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just want to take last row of page_likes (710), not the first row (700)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using string function

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%m') AS ymd_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(page_likes ORDER BY created_at DESC),',',1) AS page_likes,
  SUM(post) AS total_posts 
FROM
  demo 
WHERE created_at >= '2017-11-02 00:00:00' 
  AND created_at <= '2017-11-6 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY ymd_id 
ORDER BY ymd_id ASC
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/CVL36493)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tt.ymd_id, test.page_likes, tt.total_posts FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y%m') as ymd_id, MAX(created_at) as created_at, sum(post) AS total_posts
    FROM test
    Where created_at BETWEEN '2017-11-02 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-6 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY ymd_id
    ORDER BY ymd_id ASC) as tt 
join test on test.created_at = tt.created_at
```

**SQL FIDDLE**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b66e02/20

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
select max(page_likes) as page_likes
```

in the select block

Comment: Thanks, but it will goes wrong if someone gives a dislike on the next day